# Best practice to share controller instance across application?

Tags: node.js, telegram-bot

***What the application does***

I'm writing a `Telegram` bot using [TelegrafJS](https://telegraf.js.org/#/), so far I've created a class called `Bot` which initialize the bot `middlewares` and start it:

```
const Telegraf = require('telegraf');
const session = require('telegraf/session');

// Commands
const { commands } = require('../commands');

class Bot {

    constructor() {
        this.bot = new Telegraf(process.env.BOT_TOKEN);
        this.bot.catch(error => {
            console.error(`Bot error: ${error}`);
        });
    }

    // Init bot configuration
    async init() {

        // Set session
        this.bot.use(session.middleware());

        // Set commands
        this.bot.use(commands);
    }

    // Start the bot
    async start() {

        // Start the bot
        await this.init();
        this.bot.startPolling();
    }
}

exports.Bot = Bot;
```

the entry file `app.js` create the `Bot` instance as follow:

```
const { Bot } = require('./logic/controllers/bot.controller');
let bot = new Bot();
await bot.start();
```

***The problem***

Looking at the `commands` middleware, I have associated the `Composer` commands to the `bot`, so essentially I have:

```
const Composer = require('telegraf/composer');
const { Message } = require('../controllers/message.controller');
let msgController = new Message();

let messageCommand = new Composer();
messageCommand.action(/message-delete.+/, msgController.delete);

module.exports = messageCommand;
```

Essentially, when the user press a button which has a callback of `message-delete.message_id` the command above is triggered.

The problem is the following:

I need to use the `Telegram` bot instance inside the controller `msgController`, I've actually used the context without passing any parameters to `.delete` method, but suppose that I want store the `Telegram` bot instance somewhere that must always be accessible, how can I do this?

***What I thought***

My idea is pass the `Telegram` bot instance each time I create the instance of a class, eg:

```
const { Markup } = require('telegraf');
const moment = require('moment');

// Models
const { MessageModel } = require('../models/message.model');

class Message {
    constructor(bot){
        this.bot = bot;
    }
}
```

is that a good way to handle this or there is a better practice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The pattern you have described is called dependency injection, and is one way to fulfill the described requirement. There is nothing fundamentally wrong with this approach.

An alternative way is to use an [event-driven architecture](https://nodejs.org/api/events.html), where the app is an `eventEmitter`, and the Telegram bot listens and reacts to these events.

Here is how to implement the event-driven approach.

1. In `app.js`, the event emitter should be defined, and passed to the instantiated modules:

```
const EventEmitter = require('events');

class appEvents extends EventEmitter {}

const appEvents = new appEvents();

let bot = new Bot(appEvents);
let myMiddleware = new MyMiddleware(appEvents);
```

2. `bot.js` listens and reacts to the events:

```
appEvents.on('event', () => {
  console.log('an event occurred!');
});
```

3. The middleware modules and emit the events whenever suitable:

```
appEvents.emit('event');
```

Here, unlike in the dependency injection solution, the coupling between modules is loose: the middleware modules do not invoke explicitely the bot at all.

This loose coupling can be an advantage, as each module takes care of its business without having to worry about what happens next. In large applications though, it might get tricky to know what happens once an event is emitted (since multiple parts of the application may be listening and reacting to it.

There is plenty of litterature online about the pros and cons of both approaches, up to you to make your own opinion.